# Question about convergence of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Given a sequence $x_n$ = $\sqrt{1}$ , $-\sqrt{1}$,$\sqrt{2}$,$-\sqrt{2}$...

If $$y_n = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + \ldots +x_n}{n} $$

Then sequence $y_n$  is

1.Monotonic

2.NOT bounded

3.bounded but not convergent

4.convergent

From first observation i thought of using cauchy first theorem on limits of sequence .For that i need to evaluate limit of sequence$ x_n $ .But that limit doesnot exist as two subsequence co verge to different limit but answer is given by option 3 .I would like to know where i went wrong and what can be done here .Thanks

Comment: We have $y_{2n} = 0$ and $y_{2n+1} > 0$ for every $n,$ so $y_n$ isn't monotonic.

Comment: Moreover remark that $y_{2n+1}=\sqrt{n+1}/(2n+1)$ and squeeze.

Comment: @Tom-Tom but when i use cauchy first t

Comment: What do you call Cauchy first theorem ?

Comment: @Tom-Tom sorry i see now my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is 4. convergent

$y_{2n} = 0, y_{2n+1} = \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{2n+1}$. It's clear that sequence is not monotonic and it is bounded by 1. The subsequence $y_{2n+1}$ converges to $0$ and the subsequence $y_{2n}$ is identically $0$. Hence, the sequence $y_n$ converges to $0$.

Comment: When i use cauchy 1st theorem limit doesnt seem toexist

Comment: No, it's not contradiction to Cauchy 1st theorem. The theorem makes hypothesis that - $x_n$ converges - but $x_n$ doesn't converge here. Its a special case where $x_n$ might not have limit but $y_n$ does. There are many such examples.

Comment: Oh i was applying converse part of theorem

Comment: The converse is not true!

Comment: Yes yes sorry for blunder

Comment: You can apply the theorem only when $x_n$ converges or you can use the contrapositive statement - if $y_n$ does not converge then $x_n$ does not converge.

Comment: How you came up with expression for odd terms

Comment: You can verify by inspection!

Answer (score 2):

If n is even, $y_{n}=0$.

If n is odd, let $n=2k+1$, then $y_{n}=\frac{x_n}{n}=\frac{\sqrt{k+1}}{2k+1}$.

Therefore the sequence converges to $0$.